# Doesn't show icon from jQuery UI pack

Tags: jquery-ui

I try to use jQuery icon in my html page but when I set "class" for span it doesn't work. The span element doesn't work even if I add some extra text between tags.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple TODO list</title>

    <style type="text/css">@import url("include/css/bootstrap.min.css");</style>
    <style type="text/css">@import url("include/css/jquery-ui-git.css");</style>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not loading the jquery-ui CSS files:

```
    <link type="text/css" href="css/{theme}/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /><!-- jqueryUI theme -->
```

Comment: I loaded it in  <style type="text/css">@import url("include/css/jquery-ui-git.css");</style>

Comment: Is it actually loaded? Don't you have to select a theme to load?

Comment: I just downloaded this file from http://code.jquery.com/ and put it into my project. Isn't it correct file?

Comment: I'm afraid not.  Go here http://jqueryui.com/ and use the custom download builder.